# Solving parsing error of HTTP request header

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have currently deployed the application without SSL certificate. And, we are neither able to trace the source of the request nor obtain more details of the request.

The error thrown is as follows:

```
 `enter code here` Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:418) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:260) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

This occurs only after deployment in AWS EB + EC2 and not in my local. What can be the possible causes for the error?

Comment: You are trying to connect using TLS to a plain HTTP connector.

Comment: No,we are using TLS 1.2 to HTTPS from End to End.

Comment: _"We have currently deployed the application **without** SSL certificate"_: if you don't configure a certificate the connector will be a plain HTTP connector and will choke on the initial TLS packet. Upgrade to [Tomcat 9.0.35](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.35_(markt)) or higher if you want a better error message.